# How to get WebStorm to recognize class methods node.js

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm 11.0.3 with ES6 and node language support activated. I have a class, for example:

```
// File thing.js
'use strict';
module.exports = class Thing {
    static do(){
        console.log('thing.do1');
    }

    do(){
        console.log('do');
    }
};
```

Now I want to use this class. If I give the class a different name in the require, I don't get intellisense. E.g., this works:

```
// File do1.js
'use strict';
var Thing = require('./thing');

Thing.do();
new Thing().do();
```

But this doesn't (no intellisense on thing, no go-to-declaration, etc.)

```
// File do2.js
'use strict';
var thing = require('./thing');

thing.do();
new thing().do();
```

Is there any way around this wierdness?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can change `module.exports = class Thing` to the `export default class Thing`

And thanks for the question - appropriate issue was created (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20854)

Comment: Hm, I'm sure I already added this comment. Weird. Julia, as far as I can tell, the syntax you recommended (export default) isn't currently supported in the V8 version being used by node. Am I wrong?

Comment: Could you provide a reference link for such a syntax in the docs?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Which docs? I tried "export default" in node 4.2.2 and it isn't recognized by node and I don't see any harmony settings that apply to this.

Comment: Node still doesn't support import statements. Read more about it here: https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/an-update-on-es6-modules-in-node-js-42c958b890c